# How to line-break a link in a list

Tags: css

I'm trying to line-break links without success

How could I be able to solve this issue? I've tried word-break

I get this result:

```
foo bar *
some long sentence *
another one * third
```

instead of this

```
foo bar * some long 
sentence * another 
one * third
```

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li::after {
  content: '\2022';
  margin-left: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">foo bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">some long sentence</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">another one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-block` is doing just that: displaying block elements inline, but treating the element like a block on its own. Changing it to `display: inline` will instead display the text like a normal inline text.

Then, you don't even need the `word-wrap` anymore.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li::after {
  content: '\2022';
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">foo bar</a></li>
<li><a href="#">some long sentence</a></li>
<li><a href="#">another one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the display property for `li` from `inline-block` to `inline`

have a look to code snippet

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li::after {
  content: '\2022';
  margin-left: 5px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">foo bar</a></li>
<li><a href="#">some long sentence some long sentence some long sentence some long sentence </a></li>
<li><a href="#">another one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That does not look like the expected output defined by OP.

Comment: @connexo, sorry I read the question wrong, now its working fine